# What is .dex file in android? I am getting an error Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException;

Tags: android

I am getting an error message in android while running.

```
[2013-01-04 15:34:22 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException;
[2013-01-04 15:34:22 - ZipGrocery] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.dex` means Dalvik EXecutable. It is the format the `DVM` (Dalvik Virtual Machine) needs. The DVM is used by Android as runtime enviroment.

Your `.apk`-files contain those `.dex` ones (rename `.apk` to `.zip` and see for yourself).

So your Java-source has to be translated to .dex, that should be done by your Android-SDK when building your .apk. At this step, it seems to me, something goes wrong and therefore you get an error at runtime.

Check your code and see if you can do something about:

```
Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException;
```